# How to have a fixed element (like float: right) in a flex layout?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a flex layout with elements in it. I want one of them to always stick in the top right corner.
When I put it out of the container (below, in blue), it works for the basic cases, but in my last example, I would want the 5 box to be under the fixed one.  How can I achieve that? Maybe with grid? I never used them.
Another way to see it is to say that the space for that element should be reserved / not used by the flex elements.This way I could put the fixed one there with `position: absolute;`
[image]

Comment: How's the second example different from the 5th ?

Comment: Sorry, there is only 4 examples, what do you mean?

Comment: oh yes yes, the second and last, is it just parent width ?

Comment: I see you got an answer. But I'm just curious, what did you actually try before posting? Usually people answer questions when you show what you have already tried to do to accomplish it.

Comment: I didn't share the code as the image was way more clear in my opinion, but what I did was using flexboxes only as I don't know how grid works yet. So the 3 examples on the left where achieve with two flex containers, one black containing the blue flex container and the red fixed element, and then the blue flex container with automatic wrapping of the green elements. Doing so, I just was unable to do the "Yes" example above, so I asked for the good way to deal with this (of course, I tried float and absolute positionning before)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS grid can do this and the fixed element can be anywhere inside the container:

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,minmax(200px,1fr));
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
  grid-gap:5px;
}

.container > div {
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}

.container  .fixed {
  grid-column-end:-1; /* last column */
  grid-row:1; /* first row */
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="fixed"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```